# Translate error and validation messages in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have a store with in 3 languages: French, English (default) and German

How to translate the error messages and validation like:

> There is already an account with this
>   email address. If you are sure that it
>   is your email address, click here to
>   get your password and access your
>   account.

Are there any ready translations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use inline translations. To enable it, go to configuration > developer > inline translation. Don't forget to restrict translating tasks to your ip on the same developer tab. Then you can simply translate almost anything by simply clicking on it.

Comment: No, this works only with translation of menus and other site Magento text elements and don't works with validation and error messages generated with javascript !

Answer (score 1):

Search the message in:-

> **/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv**

Here, en_US is the locale code for US English. It is fr_FR for French and so on for other languages.

You can change it there.